# Multiple non-matching vectors

Tags: r

Assume I have the following data:

```
data <- c("a", "b", "c", "x")
set1 <- c("a")
set2 <- c("b")
set3 <- c("c")
```

I am trying to find a convenient way of identifying the elements of `data` that are not matched by sets 1-3 (or an arbitrary number of sets). In this simple example it is obviously `x`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
setdiff(data, unlist(mget(ls(pattern='^set'))))
#[1] "x"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- data[!data %in% set]
```

You can use the code above in an apply statement if you can concatenate all your sets into a dataFrame. However it would be easier to just merge all your sets and use the above statement